# Serializing an enum using the XML Serializer -- I keep the name, but lose the value. Any way to keep both?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum ComponentType
{
    None = -1,
    Equipment = 0,
    Cable = 2,
    Port = 4,
    Space = 8,
    Site = 9,
    Building = 10,
    Floor = 11,
    DataCenter = 12,
    Area = 13,
    Rack = 14,
    Conduit = 16,
    Person = 17,
    Pit = 18
}
```

I would like to use this enum on the other side of a WCF service. As such, I need to serialize it!

I see the serializer generating the following:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.website.com/api")]
public enum ComponentType {

    /// <remarks/>
    None,

    /// <remarks/>
    Equipment,

    /// <remarks/>
    Cable,

    /// <remarks/>
    Port,

    /// <remarks/>
    Space,

    /// <remarks/>
    Site,

    /// <remarks/>
    Building,

    /// <remarks/>
    Floor,

    /// <remarks/>
    DataCenter,

    /// <remarks/>
    Area,

    /// <remarks/>
    Rack,

    /// <remarks/>
    Conduit,

    /// <remarks/>
    Person,

    /// <remarks/>
    Pit,
}
```

Unfortunately, that's no good. The following code works differently on either end.

```
int componentId = 123;
int flag = ComponentDao.GetFlagForComponentById(componentId);

ComponentType componentType = ((ComponentType)flag);
//componentType == ComponentType.None (client end of service)
//componentType == ComponentType.Equipment (server end of service)
```

I looked around at some attribute decorators thinking I might find something useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx. This link shows how to change the serialization name, but does not state anything about the value.

Does this mean that I am not able to maintain my enum values using this serialization engine?

Comment: Why are you casting 0 to ComponentType instead of using ComponentType.None (or ComponentType.Equipment)?

Comment: @zimdanen That was an example. There is an integer value stored in our database. When retrieved from the database I would like to convert the integer value to its corresponding Enum value. However, the integer values correspond to different enum values due to serialization issues.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a lookup table (MS SQL) or an enum type (mySQL) for the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a direct reference to the DLL containing the enum and avoided serialization altogether. Sorry, not a great answer, but I was unable to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with the serializer itself, but with the code generation.  The generated code does not agree with your code.  This could be a bug in the code generator, or it could be that your code was modified after the code was generated.

In the second case, you should be able to fix the problem by updating the service reference (or otherwise regenerating the code).

If you're using the Data Contract Serializer, you should probably read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx.  Perhaps decorating your enum with the attributes would get the code gen to work as it should.

Comment: I've updated the service reference once, but I will delete it and re-generate from scratch to see if this resolves the issue. EDIT: Deletion and regeneration has no effect. Perhaps it is an issue with the code generator, but I suspect just a limitation on the serialization implementation. We shall see.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Does the link I just added to the answer help at all?

Comment: Sort of. I am not using the Data Contract Serializer, as shown in the code. If I was using the DCS the CodeDom compiler would change from "System.Xml" to "System.ServiceModel". This has other, interesting side-effects which I am trying to avoid. I suspect the DCS is a more up-to-date serializer, but alas, technical debt. I'll see if I can find any other way!

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

- Add an XmlEnumAttribute to each item
- Use reflection to get the attribute value and parse it to int

  ```
  public enum myEnum
  {
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
      titi,

      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
      toto
  }
  public static class myEnumExtensions
  {
      public static int toInt(this myEnum value)
      {
          MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(myEnum).
              GetMember(value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

          XmlEnumAttribute attribute = (XmlEnumAttribute) memberInfo.
              GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlEnumAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

          return int.Parse(attribute.Name);
      }
  }

  class test
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          int i = myEnum.titi.toInt();
      }
  }
  ```

Hope this helps